# Populate case selection outcomes from text file

Tags: vba, outlook

All - is it possible (and if so, how) to populate a "Select Case" from a txt file?

I am trying to build a macros which appends a reference number to then subject of an email on send.  At the moment I have userform which pops up on send, with a combobox that is populated from a txt file.  The user selects the relevant thing from the combobox, and that is appended to the end of the email subject.

The issue I have is that it seems I cannot pass the value of the combobox itself into thisoutlooksession (i.e., through a public string).  I can only pass the listindex.

To make that meaningful, though, you then need to use select case - but the actual outcome of that selection must be hard-coded. Avoiding that is the whole point of using a txt file (which will contain a running list of reference numbers).

Is there any way for me to either pass the value of the combobox (or, better yet, a list box) from the userform into thisoutlooksession, or to populate the "select case" based on the same text file?

In the latter case, so you end up with something like:

```
[Userform.Show // Code on userform sets ListNo equal to the combobox.index]

Select Case ListNo

        Case -1
             Item.Subject = Item.Subject
        Case 0
             Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " [The value of the first line in the txt file]"
        Case 1
             Item.Subject = Item.Subject & " [The value of the second line in the txt file]"
```

(etc, etc, for however many lines there may be, which will differ from user to user)

Comment: Why can't you pass the value of the combobox?  Alternatively, you can just read a specific line of the text file (Get #1,ListNo,FileBuffer : Item.Subject = Item.Subject & FileBuffer ).

Comment: As to the "why can't you" - I cannot work that out.  I presume you can, but for some reason (I'm obviously missing something) it's empty when you try to use it in the sub (which isn't true if you're passing the List Index).  Thoughts on why that might be would be much appreciated!

Comment: That would make for a better question and get you a better answer.  You should post the code that you are using to interact with `thisoutlooksession`.

Comment: Do you still want an answer or is the response to your real question sufficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521492/unable-to-pass-value-from-userform-to-module  You may delete the question if you wish.