# Unable to Pass Value from Userform to Module

Tags: vba, outlook

All, I'm trying to pass the value of a selected item (or items) from a userform into ThisOutlookSession, but cannot pass the string.  Grateful for thoughts on where I might be going wrong.

The idea is to populate a listbox with a list of references from a txt file (which works fine), the user will select an item from a list box, and that item will then be appended to the end of the subject line of an outgoing email. (The part of the code which amends the subject line is omitted from the below).

Within ThisOutlookSession:

```
Public subString As String

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

SubjectAdd.Show
[CODE OMITTED,  but the gist of it is item.subject = item.subject & strstring]

End Sub
```

Within  SubjectAdd userform:

```
Private Sub Append_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long

  lngCount = 0
  For i = 0 To MatterList.ListCount - 1
    If MatterList.Selected(i) = True Then
      lngCount = lngCount + 1
      If lngCount = 1 Then
        StrPicks = MatterList.List(i)
      Else
        StrPicks = StrPicks & " " & MatterList.List(i)
      End If
    End If
  Next i

subString = StrPicks
Me.Hide

lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Public` variable should work

As an alternative use `Tag` property of `UserForm` object

In `Append_Click()` add a final line before `Me.Hide`

```
Me.Tag = StrPicks
```

Then in `Application_ItemSend()`, before any

```
Unload SubjectAdd
```

place the following

```
subject = item.subject & SubjectAdd.Tag
```